# Flexbox resizes a checkbox (too small)

Tags: html, css, checkbox, flexbox

I've got a HTML formular-list with checkboxes. All checkboxes have a label.

I'm styling this formular with flexbox. Using flexbox makes one of the checkboxes smaller than all the others. The reason seems to be that the label text for that checkbox is so long that it needs to be wrapped in the next line.

```css
.filter-list li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
.filter-list input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-right: 2rem;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter1" type="checkbox" name="section" value="Angewandte Ingenierwissenschaften">
    <label for="filter1">Hochschule</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter2" type="checkbox" name="section" value="Angewandte Ingenierwissenschaften">
    <label for="filter2">Angewandte Ingenierwissenschaften</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter3" type="checkbox" name="section" value="Bauen & Gestalten">
    <label for="filter3">Bauen & Gestalten</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter4" type="checkbox" name="section" value="BWL">
    <label for="filter4">BWL</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter5" type="checkbox" name="section" value="Informatik">
    <label for="filter5">Informatik</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter6" type="checkbox" name="section" value="Logistik">
    <label for="filter6">Logistik</label>
</li>
```

And of course here's a Plunkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/aagWvhpvuH5sPXBXUbUH?p=preview

Here is an example with flexbox:

[image: with flexbox]

[image: without flexbox]

Anybody got an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add for the inputs:

```
flex: 1;
```

And for the labels:

```
flex: 2;
```

It works for me on chrome, firefox, IE.

Comment: I was able to achieve my desired layout with only a `flex:1` on the `label`

Comment: This will make a 1:2 ratio of sizes, rather than making the checkbox column just large enough to fit the contents.

Answer (score 7):

If you add min-width to the input in addition to width it appears to resolve the issue for me.

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    margin-right: 2rem;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `min-width` did it!

Answer (score 6):

You can set `flex:none` on items you don't want resized as part of flex calculations.

The following Information is from Tailwind CSS documentation but this applies to pure CSS too: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex#none

> Use `flex: 0 1 auto;` to allow a flex item to shrink but not grow, taking into account its initial size.

> Use `flex: 1 1 0%;` to allow a flex item to grow and shrink as needed, ignoring its initial size:

> Use `flex: 1 1 auto;` to allow a flex item to grow and shrink, taking into account its initial size:

> Use `flex: none;` to prevent a flex item from growing or shrinking:

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of a bug in Webkit, which shouldn't affect checkboxes size when they are places as a flex-child.

### [Demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/6hYgK/3/)

```css
body{ font:14 Arial; }

label {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 1.2;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

label.checkbox {
 display: inline-flex;
}

label.checkbox > input {
 line-height: 2;
 margin: 4px 0 0 0;
 width: 35px; /* THE FIX */
}
```

```html
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  This is a very verryyyyy long label for a checkbox item, try to click it!
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

I witnessed this bug on iOS Safari 13.1 – as @vsync says, this looks like a WebKit bug when using a `<input>` as a flex child.

I was able to work around this by adding an extra wrapper `<div>` around the checkbox. That is, instead of

```
<li>
    <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter2" type="checkbox" name="section" value="Angewandte Ingenierwissenschaften">
    <label for="filter2">Angewandte Ingenierwissenschaften</label>
</li>
```

writing

```
<li>
    <div>
        <input class="filterCheckbx" id="filter2" type="checkbox" name="section" value="Angewandte Ingenierwissenschaften">
    </div>
    <label for="filter2">Angewandte Ingenierwissenschaften</label>
</li>
```

In my testing, this solution correctly sizes the left column to be only as wide as needed to fit the checkbox.