# My checkbox inputs stays ridiculously small on IOS 13.7

Tags: css, ios, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wonder if you can help me please. I have multiple checkbox inputs and I tested in many devices and browsers. Only in Apple 13.7 I see my checkboxes inputs round and really small, like this in the image:

[image]

My html:

```css
form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.dataallow {
    display: flex;
}

.dataallow input {
    margin-right: 8px;
}

label {
    color: #595959;
}

.dataallow label {
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.size-small {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">               
    <div class="form-group dataallow">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label class="gray-25 size-small">Text text text text</label>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">               
    <div class="form-group dataallow">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label class="gray-25 size-small">Text text text text</label>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also use bootstrap 3 in it.

Comment: I copied your code to a codepen and check it from my phone ios 13.7 as well.  and they look like pretty normal compare to your image. Here in case some want to try: https://codepen.io/Maxigui/pen/vYKBQzQ

Comment: Also look fine on iPad IOS 13.6.1

Comment: I think I found out the solution of the problem. WhenI put a lot of text in the label, the checkbox stays really small. Maybe if I put a width and height in the checkbox it solves that issue.

Comment: Yes, adding extra text to the label gradually changes the size of the checkable box. Does this [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220553/flexbox-resizes-a-checkbox-too-small help?

Comment: try adding flex-shrink:0 to checkbox input

Answer (score 8):

Just add a `min-width: 20px` to the input element.

It happens in iOS when the label has a lenght more than usual.