# Custom Checkboxes don't work in Safari on iPad. They also don't work in Firefox or Chrome on the same device

Tags: css, ipad, checkbox, safari

My CSS styles appear not to be applied to the checkboxes on iPad 10. I first discovered the problem on Safari, which then made me think that there might be some default browser styles which I couldn't overwrite yet, but since this problem also occurs in Firefox and Chrome on the same device it's more likely that the reason for this might be the iPad itself.

In detail:

- the checkboxes appear like this:

[Safari/Firefox/Chrome on iPad 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFBm8.png)

They hang above the text instead of being aligned in the center of the block. They also shrink in size depending on the size of the subsequent paragraph.

They should appear like this:

[Firefox on Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite and Firefox on Windows PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCO6r.png)

The CSS code for the checkboxes is as following:

```
.input-container {
    display: flex;
    text-align: justify;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.checkboxes {
display: flex;
justify-content: left;
align-items: right;
vertical-align: middle;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div class="input-container" 
     style="text-align:justify; hyphens:auto; width:60%; 
            margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <p>
         Anschließende Zentrifugation der Probe, Gegengewicht nicht vergessen! 8.000 rpm für 10 min.
      </p>
</div>
```

I already tried 'appearance: none;' or '-webkit-appearance: none;' to remove default browser styles as well as !important, put the css styles at the end of the stylesheet to avoid lastrule but nothing worked so far. Apple customer support could not help me with getting insight into default browser styles (I don't have access to a mac to connect the iPad with and use Webinspector...).

Why don't the checkboxes appear properly on the iPad 10?

Comment: Bear in mind that browsers on IOS are basically all the same under the skin so I'd expect e.g. Chrome and Safari to give the same result.

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet, and check that it shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @A Haworth here's a runnible snippet - I confirm that the problem still appears only on iPad

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="2.1.1_StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>SOP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="input-container" style="text-align:justify;hyphens:auto;width:60%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <p>Anschließende Zentrifugation der Probe, Gegengewicht nicht vergessen! 8.000 rpm für 10 min.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: CSS:

html {
background-color: #f5f3ee;
text-align: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-origin: content-box;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
text-align: center;
min-height: screen;
height: 100%;
width: 75%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 18%;
}
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
  }
  .checkboxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
 align-items: right;
 vertical-align: middle;
 word-wrap: break-word;
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220553/flexbox-resizes-a-checkbox-too-small

Found a working solution for the size issue